# iOS7 what is the difference in all these color, "barTintColor, tintColor, backgroundColor, UITextAttributeTextColor"?

Tags: ios7, tintcolor

I am totally confused about all these color setting in navigationController in iOS7. Can someone tell me what exact difference are among all these things? I tried to figure out some of them, but not sure whether I am right.

Thank you!

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor redColor];//???

self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];//???

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];//the text colour of backButton of the navigationBar???

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]};//the text color of the title of the navigationBar

 [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor greyColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];//the text colour of the customised rightButton in the navigationBar
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the difference between above :

**barTintColor :** The tint color to apply to the navigation bar background.

**backgroundColor :** change the background color of navigationBar

**tintColor :** The tint color to apply to the navigation items and bar button items.

**UITextAttributeTextColor :**  Key to the text color in a text attributes dictionary.The corresponding value is an instance of UIColor.  `Available in iOS 5.0 and later.Deprecated in iOS 7.0.` It’s an `easy fix`. Just change `UITextAttributeTextColor to NSForegroundColorAttributeName`

Here is the more details : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Comment: So what exactly is the tint color? I thought it was just the color of the items.

Comment: tintColor is "The tint color to apply to the navigation items and bar button items." Its apply to the barItems and buttons.

Comment: "The tint color to apply to the navigation bar background' ? you didn't explain anything...